# Por que o $fat começa com 1 no cálculo de fatorial?

Tags: php

Por que neste código o valor `$fat` começa com 1?

É um código para achar o fatorial de um número (`$v = valor`):

```
<?php
    $v = isset($_GET["valor"])?$_GET["valor"]:1;
    echo "<h1>Calculando o fatorial de $v</h1>";
    $c = $v;
    $fat = 1;
    do {
        $fat = $fat * $c;
        $c--;
    } while ($c>=1);
    echo "<h2>$v! = $fat</h2>";
?>
```

O código também pode ser visto [aqui](https://repl.it/@matheusdouradob/SpringgreenNavyEntropy).

Comment: Fatorial de um número é a multiplicação dele por todos os seus antecessores maiores que zero. O fato de utilizar `$fat` como 1, faz com que não se necessite de variáveis auxiliares ao cálculo, pois, o fatorial é calculado utilizando apenas a variável $fat e o número inicial ($c) ou seu antecessor ($c--) a cada iteração. Se `$fat` não tivesse valor, seria considerado zero, o produto de zero é zero. A condição poderia ainda ser `$c > 1`, pois, não tem necessidade de multiplicar por 1. Além disso, a ordem dos fatores não alteram o produto.

Comment: mas o valor fat tem que ser diferente de 1 para multiplicar com o $c na equação $fat = $fat * $c

isto que n consigo entender

Comment: O que você acabou de dizer não faz sentido. Faça um teste de mesa por iteração, ficará fácil de entender. Digamos que faça o fatorial de 5. Primeira iteração é (`$fat = 1 * 5 -> 5`), segunda `$fat = 5 * 4 -> 20`, terceira `$fat = 20 * 3 -> 60`, quarta e última `$fat = 60 * 2 -> 120`. Se você não utilizar da forma que foi apresentado, terás que utilizar variáveis auxiliares para o valor de fatorial e qual é o valor corrente do cálculo. Utilizar `$fat = 1` é apenas uma das inúmeras formas de lógica que podem ser empregadas.

Comment: Reforçando o que o @GabrielHeming disse e respondendo com uma frase super simples: porque é o elemento neutro da multiplicação

Comment: se $fat começa com 1, aonde esta escrito no código o valor para ele multiplicar com $c, se for fatorial de $c = $v, se $v é igual ao valor escolhido vamos supor 3, 
ai $c = $v = 3
ai fica $fat = 1 (começa com valor 1)
ai depois $fat = $fat * $c (nesta linha como o php atribui um valor diferente de 1 ao $fat?)

to bugando nesta parte entre parenteses rs

Comment: Nesse caso começa com `$fat = 1 * 3` que dá 3. Lembre-se que qualquer numero multiplicado por 1 dá o próprio numero e é por esse motivo que o 1 é o elemento neutro da multiplicação.

Answer (score 1):

É o que chamamos de elemento neutro da operação.

Esse valor, `$fat = 1`, sempre estará ali independente de qual é o valor de entrada, isto é, se estamos calculando o fatorial de 5 ou 345; `$fat` sempre começará com o valor 1.

Por que exatamente o 1?

Porque precisamos garantir que esse valor inicial não interfira, de maneira alguma, no nosso resultado e, para isso, atribuímos como valor inicial o valor neutro da multiplicação.

O valor neutro, `X`, de uma operação é aquele que quando efetuada a operação o resultado seja o outro operando. Por exemplo, `X * A` precisa ser `A` para que `X` seja considerado o elemento neutro. Somente se `X = 1` o resultado será `A`, independente do valor de `A`.

O mesmo acontece com o valor 0 quando a operação matemática é a adição, pois `0 + A` sempre será `A`, independente do valor de `A`.

Desta forma, iniciando `$fat = 1`, garantimos que quando for executado `$fat = $fat * $c` o resultado será `$c` independente do valor de `$c`.